# want to install react but facing spawn error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\Vishnu\react> npx create-react-app vikas

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Vishnu\react\vikas.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


Aborting installation.
Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:
Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:412:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:698:9)
    at spawn (C:\Users\Vishnu\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js:12:24)
    at C:\Users\Vishnu\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:407:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at install (C:\Users\Vishnu\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:359:10)
    at C:\Users\Vishnu\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:485:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting vikas/ from C:\Users\Vishnu\react
Done.
PS C:\Users\Vishnu\react> npx create-react-app vikas
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Following Steps.

1. open powershell/cmd and run.

   `npm cache clean --force`
2. Run
   `npm cache verify`
3. Run
   `npm install create-react-app vikas`
4. Run
   `npx  create-react-app vikas`